# c# regex.split not working on chrome

Tags: c#, regex

I use below code to retrieve lines from a multiline asp:textbox

```
string[] SerialNumbers = Regex.Split(txtSerials.Text.Trim(), "\r\n");
```

It works as expected in IE, but in Chrome it doesn't, please refer to below example:

**IE:**

```
SerialNumbers[0]="Line1"
SerialNumbers[1]="Line2"
```

**Chrome:**

```
SerialNumbers[0]="Line1\nLine2"
```

Comment: Have you tried Environment.Newline instead of "\r\n"?

Comment: it is because the text returned by `IE` as `txtSerials.Text` is `"Line1\r\nLine2"` but from `Chrome` is `"Line1\nLine2"`.

Comment: @Matt `Environment.Newline` represents the local machine standard, not what comes from the browser.

Comment: @Matt didn't work with `Environment.Newline`

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon looked like it was being executed on the server

Comment: @Matt it **is**. But the data comes from a browser. So, you don't know if it's sending you \r or \r\n.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx "A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried normalizing the line breaks in the textbox:

```
string[] SerialNumbers = Regex.Split(
    txtSerials.Text
       .Replace("\r\n", "\n")
       .Trim(),
    "\n");
```

You're also using a regex when regular `String.Split` would suffice:

```
string [] SerialNumbers = txtSerials.Text
   .Replace("\r\n", "\n")
   .Trim()
   .Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the split method on a string.

```
string [] SerialNumbers = txtSerials.Text
    .Trim()
    .Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to be `\r?\n`, so it will work with both `\r\n` (CR+LF, DOS/Windows standard) and `\n` (LF only, Unix standard)

From the results you're seeing, it seems like Chrome is using the latter.

Answer (score -1):

There are two themes of answers so far and I suspect the best will be to use both in the following manner:

```
            var serialText = new StringBuilder();

        serialText.Append("Foo\n");
        serialText.Append("Bar\r");
        serialText.Append("Baz\r\n");
        serialText.AppendFormat("Pok{0}", Environment.NewLine);
        serialText.AppendLine("Zok");

        string[] serials = serialText.ToString().Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

        foreach (var s in serials)
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

This will maintain portability as well as your stated business needs.

Comment: It is odd that you provide a wrong answer, although (A) there are already 3 correct answers, and (B) the OP already stated in the comments that `Environment.NewLine` is not working for his case. o_O

Comment: When I started drafting the answer, no mention of ```Environment.NewLine``` existed in the question.

Comment: And now I see I didn't paste the full answer that I drafted. Edit incoming.

Comment: Still wrong, because you still simply assume that the line breaks in the string are the same as Environment.NewLine and ignore the question. There simply is no reason to assume this, unless the string has been created as in your example. However, this is obviously not the case as explained in the question - there the strings were coming from web browsers, and the composition of those strings is beyond the control of the OP...